Problem with total internal reflection in ray tracing (Ray tracing in a weekend)
I'm following the steps in the book 'Ray Tracing in a weekend' and I'm having some problems with the section 11.3 Total internal reflection. When I try create the image I get this result:

This is the code for the intersection with the sphere, it returns an intersection with the sphere or null:
std::optional<Intersection> Sphere::intersect(const Ray& r, double tMin, double tMax) const {
    vec o_c = this->center- r.origin();

    auto a = r.direction().length_squared() () 
    auto b = dot(r.direction(), o_c);
    auto c = o_c.length_squared() - radius * radius;
    
    auto d = b * b - a * c;

    // at^2 + tb + c = 0 not real solution

    if (d < 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    // Verify root in [tMin, tMax]

   double dSqrt = std::sqrt(d);
    double root = (b - dSqrt) / a;
    if (root < tMin || root > tMax) {
        root = (b + dSqrt) / a;
        if (root < tMin || root > tMax) return std::nullopt;
    }

    Intersection i;
    i.t = root;
    i.point = r(i.t);
    i.normal = unit_vector(i.point - center);
        i.material = material;

    return i;
 };

This is the code for the refraction:
inline vec refraction(const vec& v, const vec& normal, double refraction_index) {
    vec rparal{ .0, .0, .0 };
    vec rperp{ .0, .0, .0 };

    bool front_face = (dot(v, normal) < 0);
    double ri = front_face ? 1.0 / refraction_index : refraction_index;

    vec outward_normal = front_face ? normal : -normal;
    
    double cos_tita = fmin(dot(-v, outward_normal ), 1.0);
    double sen_tita = sqrt(1 - cos_tita * cos_tita);

    
    if (ri * sen_tita > 1) {
        return reflect(v, outward_normal);
    }
    
    rperp = ri * (v + (dot(-v, outward_normal) * outward_normal)); 
    rparal = (-sqrt(abs(1 - rperp.length_squared()))) * outward_normal;

    return rparal + rperp;
};

And this is the code for the color_ray:
color color_ray(const Ray& r, int deep, const Geometry& g) {

    if (deep <= 0)
        return color(0, 0, 0);

    auto i = g.intersect(r, 0.001, infinity);

    if (i) {
        color intensity;

         // Check if the material is reflective
        if (i->material->reflective) {

            vec reflectedVector = reflect(unit_vector(r.direction()), i->normal) + 
            (i->material->coef_Reflective * vec::random_Unit_vector());

            Ray reflected_Ray = Ray(i->point, reflectedVector);
            intensity = i->material->DifuseColor * color_ray(reflected_Ray, deep - 1, g);

         // Check if the material is refractive
        } else if (i->material->refractive) {

           vec refractedVector = refraction(unit_vector(r.direction()), i->normal, 
                                 i->material>refraction_index);

       Ray refracted_Ray = Ray(i->point, refractedVector);
           intensity = color_ray(refracted_Ray , deep - 1, g);

        } else {

            intensity = i->material->DifuseColor * color_ray(Ray(i->point, i->normal +                    vec::randomUnitVector()), deep - 1, g);

        }

        return intensity;
    }
    
    vec unit_direction = unit_vector(r.direction());
    auto a = 0.5 * (unit_direction .y() + 1);
    return (1.0 - a) * color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) + a * color(0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
};


I should get the following image as a result:

Let me know if you need more information, any help is appreciated :)

The quadratic formula doesn't look correct to me. The determinant is typically expressed as b*b - 4*a*c and a root as (-b +/- sqrt(det))/(2*a) - even if the coefficients have been scaled, both expressions can't be right in that code.

Hello @BrettHale, thanks for the answer. I followed the steps in the section 6.2 and in the section 6.3, where it simplifies the code for the intersection with the sphere, you can check that if you want. I checked the code again just to be sure and I think that there is not an error there, but I will go through it again just in case, thanks!

In the book b = -2 * dot (r.direction(), o_c), if we use h = dot (r.direction(), o_c) and
b = -2h we will get the ecuations in the code for the root and  the discriminant .
Let me know if I am missing anything.

I just posted the solution, thanks for commenting @BrettHale, have a nice day!

Well, I found the solution, the problem was in
rparal = (-sqrt(abs(1 - rperp.length_squared()))) * outward_normal;
I deleted the parenthesis and I changed 'abs' for 'fabs' and that solved the problem.
rparal = -sqrt(fabs(1 - rperp.length_squared())) * outward_normal;
Here is the new image generated: New image without problem

You could just use std::abs (also for the other maths functions) to select the right version depending on your arguments. Everything in your code should be either float or double. You might also want to increase your compiler's warning levels, as this looks like loss of precision your compiler should tell you about.
